# Emailing with Classic ASP

Tags: email, asp-classic

Aim:

Email clients from admin@companywebsite.com

Issue:

Firstly let me say I am a .Net developer but I have been asked to look at the below to support my clients existing site they are having issues in as the new one will not be up for 6 months.

The Server it is sat on is sat on a different server domain i.e. outsourcedcompany.companywebsite.com and when we email out the emails are going to info@companywebsite.com etc. but not to say info@gmail.com

How can I help myself:

I will be able to set up admin@companywebsite.com on the server to send out emails to the client if we need to and it helps

Code:

```
'This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.

    'Custom Code @211-73254650  
' -------------------------  
Dim FireUPRN  
Dim FRADate  
Dim SurveyCompany  
Dim Assessor  
Dim TaskType  
Dim Task  
Dim ActionType  
Dim Priority  
Dim RecommendationDate  
Dim TaskAllocatedDate  
Dim TaskAllocatedTo  
Dim TargetDate  
Dim TaskStatus  
Dim TaskComments  
Dim Photo  
Dim AssigneeEmailAddress  
Dim Bodytxt  

FireUPRN = Request.Form("FireUPRN")  
FRADate = Request.Form("FRADate")  
SurveyCompany = Request.Form("SurveyCompany")  
Assessor = Request.Form("Assessor")  
TaskType = Request.Form("TaskType")  
Task = Request.Form("Task")  
ActionType = Request.Form("ActionType")  
Priority = Request.Form("Priority")  
RecommendationDate = Request.Form("RecommendationDate")  
TaskAllocatedDate = Request.Form("TaskAllocatedDate")  
TaskAllocatedTo = Request.Form("TaskAllocatedTo")  
TargetDate = Request.Form("TargetDate")  
TaskStatus = Request.Form("TaskStatus")  
TaskComments = Request.Form("TaskComments")  
Photo = Request.Form("Photo")  

AssigneeEmailAddress = Request.Form("AssigneeEmailAddress")  

Dim ObjSendMail  
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")  

'This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.  
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).  
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mail.COMPANY-NAME.com"   
'changed 25 to 465  
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25  
'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)  
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False    
'Timeout  
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60  
'If your server requires outgoing authentication uncomment the lines bleow and use a valid email address and password.  
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication  
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "webmaster@COMPANY-NAME.com"   
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "villa1982"     

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update  
'End remote SMTP server configuration section==  

ObjSendMail.To = Request.Form("AssigneeEmailAddress")  
ObjSendMail.Subject = "Assigned Fire Risk Assessment Task, which must be carried out within the stated timescale."  
ObjSendMail.From = "webmaster@COMPANY-NAME.com"   
'ObjSendMail.CC = "someone@someone.net"  
'ObjSendMail.AddAttachment "c:\myweb\somefile.jpg"  

Bodytxt = "You have been assigned a FRA Task, the details are the following: " & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "UPRN: " &FireUPRN & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "FRA Date: " &FRADate & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Survey Company: " &SurveyCompany & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Assessor: " &Assessor & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Task Type: " &TaskType & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Task: " &Task & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Action Type: " &ActionType & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Priority: " &Priority & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Recommendation Date: " &RecommendationDate & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Task Allocated Date: " &TaskAllocatedDate & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Task Allocated To: " &TaskAllocatedTo & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Target Date: " &TargetDate & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Task Status: " &TaskStatus & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Task Comments: " &TaskComments & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Photo: " &Photo & VbCrLf & VbCrLf  

ObjSendMail.TextBody = Bodytxt ' body text  
ObjSendMail.Send     'send command  
Set ObjSendMail = Nothing 'reset mail  

' -------------------------  
'End Custom Code
```

Comment: When you email someone with x@companyname.com it works but if you try to email x@gmail.com / x@yahoo.com / x@anywhere else it does not send the email

Comment: have you tried emailing with the same account from e.g. outllook? does that work?

Comment: The sending and recieving email addresses work and are used on a daily basis in outlook.

Comment: Looking at your configuration settings I'd try EITHER changing the use SSL setting to True, OR changing the port to 587

Comment: No joy sadly, it seems to do something now rather than timeout but no email being received

Comment: Are you receiving any "delivery failed" messages at  admin@companywebsite.com

Comment: tell us the error message. you can do an error resume next around the send method: on error resume next
 ObjSendMail.Send     'send command  
if err.number <> 0 then 
 response.write err.description
 response.end
end if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sounds as if you are making the erroneous conclusion that if you can send to some recipients but not others, then there is something wrong with your email sending code. Think of it this way... the code above is building an email message that it is going to give to a specified SMTP server to deliver. That SMTP server is the one you specify in the second configuration field in your code (configuration/smtpserver).

The real problem you are most likely encountering has more to do with mail routing and delivery. If you are specifying from addresses for a different domain than what your mail server is setup to forward SMTP mail for, then it is either getting rejected at your mail server or one of the next SMTP servers it attempts to forward the message to either in between or at the actual destination SMTP server for the recipients inbox. Try using a plain SMTP client using the same SMTP server settings above and you will see the same results.

Comment: Okay so it works to the domain I am on if there is not authentication but to no other domain. I am looking now at the domain settings with the client to ensure they have been using the right settings. It might well be as simple as that!